# Classify images on basics of similarity

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, image-processing, aws-lambda, classification

I have 30 ,40 pictures of humans , Which I want to get in Python code . And make group of similar pics . Like 5 pic of john  and 10 of peter . like this . I am new in Image processing thing. So my question is which algo is best for this . And I want to do this on  AWS lambda function . Any help would be highly appreciated.

P.S (Its my first ever task in this field. Kindly ignore mistakes of tell me to improve them Thanks)

Comment: Did you already checkout out Amazon Rekognition?

Comment: [Check out this lab on Amazon Rekognition](https://qwiklabs.com/focuses/846?parent=catalog) which explains a practical example of identifying faces.

Comment: @AsadFerozAli  link is  about faces between video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to do the thing with AWS Rekognition. It's pretty simple.
You can achieve what you want in 3 simple steps:

**1. Uploading images with metadata:** means you are uploading images of person with their names to **s3** to store their info to be referenced later

**2. Indexing of photos** **:** this means adding info tags to faces , this info is stored in dynamodb and this is done with ***index_faces*** api

**3. Comparision of photos with indexed faces :** this will be achieved with rekognition ***search_faces_by_image*** api

Now part 1 code: *batch uploading with metadata*

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

# Get list of objects for indexing
images=[('image01.jpeg','Albert Einstein'),
      ('image02.jpeg','Candy'),
      ('image03.jpeg','Armstrong'),
      ('image04.jpeg','Ram'),
      ('image05.jpeg','Peter'),
      ('image06.jpeg','Shashank')
      ]

# Iterate through list to upload objects to S3   
for image in images:
    file = open(image[0],'rb')
    object = s3.Object('rekognition-pictures','index/'+ image[0])
    ret = object.put(Body=file,
                    Metadata={'FullName':image[1]}
                    )
```

Now part 2 code: *Indexing*

```
from __future__ import print_function

import boto3
from decimal import Decimal
import json
import urllib

print('Loading function')

dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition')


# --------------- Helper Functions ------------------

def index_faces(bucket, key):

    response = rekognition.index_faces(
        Image={"S3Object":
            {"Bucket": bucket,
            "Name": key}},
            CollectionId="family_collection")
    return response

def update_index(tableName,faceId, fullName):
    response = dynamodb.put_item(
        TableName=tableName,
        Item={
            'RekognitionId': {'S': faceId},
            'FullName': {'S': fullName}
            }
        ) 

# --------------- Main handler ------------------

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get the object from the event
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.unquote_plus(
        event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'].encode('utf8'))

    try:

        # Calls Amazon Rekognition IndexFaces API to detect faces in S3 object 
        # to index faces into specified collection

        response = index_faces(bucket, key)

        # Commit faceId and full name object metadata to DynamoDB

        if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
            faceId = response['FaceRecords'][0]['Face']['FaceId']

            ret = s3.head_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=key)
            personFullName = ret['Metadata']['fullname']

            update_index('family_collection',faceId,personFullName)

        # Print response to console
        print(response)

        return response
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Error processing object {} from bucket {}. ".format(key, bucket))
       raise e
```

Now part 3 code : Compare

```
import boto3
import io
from PIL import Image

rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name='eu-west-1')
dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1')

image = Image.open("group1.jpeg")
stream = io.BytesIO()
image.save(stream,format="JPEG")
image_binary = stream.getvalue()


response = rekognition.search_faces_by_image(
        CollectionId='family_collection',
        Image={'Bytes':image_binary}                                       
        )

for match in response['FaceMatches']:
   print (match['Face']['FaceId'],match['Face']['Confidence'])

    face = dynamodb.get_item(
        TableName='family_collection',  
        Key={'RekognitionId': {'S': match['Face']['FaceId']}}
        )

    if 'Item' in face:
        print (face['Item']['FullName']['S'])
    else:
        print ('no match found in person lookup')
```

with above compare function you will get the names of faces in photos , then you can decide what you want to do next, like storing photos with same names to a different folder by renaming the photos, this will give photos of different people in different folders

***Prerequisites:***

create a rekognition collection named **family_collection**

```
aws rekognition create-collection --collection-id family_collection --region eu-west-1
```

create a dynamodb table named **family_collection**

```
aws dynamodb create-table --table-name family_collection \
--attribute-definitions AttributeName=RekognitionId,AttributeType=S \
--key-schema AttributeName=RekognitionId,KeyType=HASH \
--provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=1,WriteCapacityUnits=1 \
--region eu-west-1
```

Comment: hi , Wao thanks for help . its so beautifuly explained . can I ask one thing more ?  where these code are to be write ?  In lambda function ?  and when they will trigger ?  thank you so much again

Comment: ya , you will write these codes in lambda functions , the indexing function and comparision function will run in lambda , and the photo uploading code you have to run in local machine as you will use it to upload images from your computer in one single go.

Comment: ya the trigger, lambda will get triggered as soon as you upload any of your image to s3 bucket

but beware of one thing that PIL or PILLOW is an image processing python library which is not a standard python library found in lambda environment , hence you will need a custom deployment package and then deploy it .

here is how you will do it :

**https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-python**

Comment: thanks for reply .Okay got it . I want to upload images from local machine to dropbox then from dropbox to S3 . So I have to change that   'Uploading images with metadata'  function on local machine. ?

Comment: Should I use 2 databases as 1 in local web application and 1 on aws live server  such as dynamodb ?

Comment: No, dynamodb is enough , u don't need anything else

Comment: And last thing I have to create separate lambda functions for indexing and Compare ? as I have only one editor on aws lambda console

Comment: can I have your any contact ? need few minutes of you if possible ?

Comment: DM me on Twitter , @mausam1997

Comment: there is no option to send you DM , I just followed you from this id  @Touseefnoor   kindly msg me please

Comment: and in this answer there is no way define to save my uploaded data to dynamodb ? like I am getting    "errorType": "ResourceNotFoundException",
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the IndexFaces operation: The collection id: athlete_collection does not exist"