# Use facial recognition to identify how many unique faces in a collection of photos

Tags: google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition, amazon-rekognition, face-api

I've never used facial recognition, but I am interested in trying. I run a yearbook program at our school and we need a rough estimate of how many unique faces we have in a collection of photos.

All the photos are on a hard drive and we need someone (or something ;) to identify how many unique faces there are.

I've done my fair share of research and I think I might want to use Amazon, Google, or Microsoft, but have no ideas what to do or where to start.

Answer (score 0):

you can try aws detect-faces api from AWS Rekognition to do so

[documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_DetectFaces.html)

see this also for reference in python boto3 to start using AWS Rekognition

[sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387735/classify-images-on-basics-of-similarity/50392007?noredirect=1#comment88437807_50392007)

Answer (score 0):

The best choice would be to use [Face API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/face)'s face grouping as it allows you to organize many unidentified faces together into groups, based on their visual similarity.

It also has a lot samples for different languages and platforms available to get you started right away that can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=face%20api&type=&language=)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use Google Cloud Platform, you can use Google Vision API [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/vision/). There is a tutorial on how to detect faces [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/face-tutorial), and different languages you can choose from.

If you want to make a test without having to code anything, in the first link I sent, you can upload some pictures and see how it works.