# how to store personal information for an image using amazon rekognition

Tags: amazon-rekognition

i am trying to create a app which makes use of amazon rekogition in aws for identification of a person and retrieving the personal information for an internal storage system.i wanted to know how to connect the amazon rekognition part
and the information stored in the database.The face detection  part will be done by amazon rekognition but how will store and retrieve the personal information after detection of face

Comment: this question might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387735/classify-images-on-basics-of-similarity/50392007#50392007

Answer (score 1):

You can attach `ExternalImageId` while you are training the face, and that `ExternalImageId` can map to the primary key in your database.

`ExternalImageId` is returned in the search results of all APIs.

Refer:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_Face.html#rekognition-Type-Face-ExternalImageId